# Laravel Fortify Logout specific

Tags: php, laravel, logout, fortify

I'm using Laravel 10 Fortify and i'm trying to get the logout action

Here what i have in my FortifyServiceProvider.php for the logout in the boot function
        `$this->app->singleton( \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse::class, \App\Http\Responses\LogoutResponse::class );`
And i'm trying to get the logout action here in the Controller\Http\Responses\LogoutResponse.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse as LogoutResponseContract;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class LogoutResponse implements LogoutResponseContract
{
    /**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse('', 204)
            : redirect('/');
    }
}
```

but when i print_r the $request, it's print nothing, i don't get the user.Do you know how can i do to have it ? can i get it on before this step ? thx

I tried to use the destroy method in the AuthenticatedSessionController.php but it never go in.

Comment: There’s not going to be an authenticated user though, because they’ve logged out. Why are you trying to get an authenticated user in a logged out response? _Logged out_ being the operative phrase here…

Comment: I have to get the logout action in a database table for each users

Comment: That makes no sense. There _isn’t_ a user if you’ve logged them out.

Answer (score 0):

When you logout, the **'$request'** object does not contain the authenticated user. So, try to create a custom method in **AuthenticatedSessionController.php** where you can get the user name and then logout.

Add :

```
 public function customLogout(Request $request)
{
    // Get the authenticated user
    $user = $request->user();

    // Perform anything before logging out

    $this->guard()->logout();
    return redirect('/'); 
}
```

And in your **web.php** add your custom route for logout :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticatedSessionController;

Route::get('/custom-logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'customLogout'])->name('custom.logout');
```

Hope this helps.